Maximum distance between two extreme points of a polyhedron
Let $P := \{x:Ax\le b\} $ and $V := \{x\in P: x = \frac{x^1+x^2}{2} \implies x^1 = x^2 = x\}$. i.e., $V$ is the set of extreme points of $P$. Assume $P$ is bounded.
Is there a fast algorithm to compute $\max\{d(u,v) :u, v \in V\}$, where $d$ is the Euclidean distance between two points.
In other words, I want to find the distance between two farthest extreme points in a polyhedron.
Is this problem easier if we use $\ell_1$ or $\ell_\infty$ distances instead of $\ell_2$?

Are you looking for something faster than solving the natural QP or LP?

No, a convex QP/LP will be enough. But in the naive formulation, we will have a convex-quadratic objective which we will maximise. Or an LP where we can't write absolute value exactly since we are maximising.

Adding to previous comment - in general, maximising a convex quadratic function over a polytope is NP-hard. A poly-time also will suffice for the above specific case.

My intuition says that this particular problem is NP-hard as well. The quantity you are looking for is also known as the diameter of a convex set, so maybe that will help the search. Solvers handle non-convex quadratic optimization quite well these days, so it may be worth it to just try to solve the problem with Gurobi for example.

No, I am looking for a theoretical poly-time algorithm :) For the $\ell_1$ or $\ell_\infty$, there is a very natural MILP formulation, which gets solved very fast with generic solvers. I am sure, it will be similar for $\ell_2$.

For the $\ell_\infty$ norm, this is computable in poly-time.
For each dimension $i$, compute $z_i = \max\{x_i \mid x\in P\} - \min\{x_i \mid x\in P\}$. Now, $z^*=\max \{z_1, \ldots, z_n\}$ answers the question.
Using usual norm-inequalities one can get approximations bounds. For example, the $\ell_1$ distance is at least $z^*$ and at most $n z^*$; $\ell_2$ distance is at least $z^*$ and at most $\sqrt{n} z^*$ etc.

Still waiting for stronger results for norms other than the $\ell_\infty$ norm.
